# JavaScript error on one address and in another not

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2013 site published in 2 address. In one I have a simple AAM and another I have the same more FBA (in a extended Web Application).

In the first, I no have any problems. In the second I have JavaScript errors and the Web Parts, lists and libraries are not loaded.

I have this errors in developer tools:

[image]

Someone can help me?

**Edit**

Function are getting error:

```
var _spRegionalSettings = {
    adjustHijriDays : 0,
    calendarType : 1,
    firstDayOfWeek : 0,
    firstWeekOfYear : 0,
    localeId : 1046,
    currentDateInLocalCalendar : new Date( 2016, 7, 12 ),
    showWeeks : 0,
    timeZone : '-03:00:00.0008461',
    timeZoneInHours : -3,
    workDayEnd : 1020,
    workDayStart : 480,
    workDays : '0111110',
    time24 : 1
};
Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ( function( a ) {
    return new Sys.CultureInfo( a.name, a.numberFormat, a.dateTimeFormat );
} )( {
    "dateTimeFormat" : {
        "AMDesignator" : "",
        "AbbreviatedDayNames" : ["dom", "seg", "ter", "qua", "qui", "sex", "sáb"],
        "AbbreviatedLeapMonthNames" : null,
        "AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames" : [
            "jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez", ""
        ],
        "AbbreviatedMonthNames" : [
            "jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez", ""
        ],
        "Calendar" : {
            "AlgorithmType" : 1,
            "CalendarType" : 1,
            "Eras" : [1],
            "IsReadOnly" : false,
            "MaxSupportedDateTime" : "\/Date(253402300799999)\/",
            "MinSupportedDateTime" : "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
            "TwoDigitYearMax" : 2029
        },
        "CalendarWeekRule" : 0,
        "DateSeparator" : "\/",
        "DayNames" : [
            "domingo", "segunda-feira", "terça-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira", "sexta-feira", "sábado"
        ],
        "FirstDayOfWeek" : 0,
        "FullDateTimePattern" : "dddd, d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "IsReadOnly" : true,
        "LeapMonthNames" : null,
        "LongDatePattern" : "dddd, d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy",
        "LongTimePattern" : "HH:mm:ss",
        "MonthDayPattern" : "d' de 'MMMM",
        "MonthGenitiveNames" : [
            "janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro",
            "novembro", "dezembro", ""
        ],
        "MonthNames" : [
            "janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro",
            "novembro", "dezembro", ""
        ],
        "NativeCalendarName" : "Calendário gregoriano",
        "PMDesignator" : "",
        "RFC1123Pattern" : "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'",
        "ShortDatePattern" : "dd\/MM\/yyyy",
        "ShortTimePattern" : "HH:mm",
        "ShortestDayNames" : ["D", "S", "T", "Q", "Q", "S", "S"],
        "SortableDateTimePattern" : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",
        "TimeSeparator" : ":",
        "UniversalSortableDateTimePattern" : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
        "YearMonthPattern" : "MMMM' de 'yyyy",
        "eras" : [1, "d.C.", "d.C.", 0]
    },
    "name" : "pt-BR",
    "numberFormat" : {
        "CurrencyDecimalDigits" : 2,
        "CurrencyDecimalSeparator" : ",",
        "CurrencyGroupSeparator" : ".",
        "CurrencyGroupSizes" : [3],
        "CurrencyNegativePattern" : 9,
        "CurrencyPositivePattern" : 2,
        "CurrencySymbol" : "R$",
        "DigitSubstitution" : 1,
        "IsReadOnly" : true,
        "NaNSymbol" : "NaN (Não é um número)",
        "NativeDigits" : ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
        "NegativeInfinitySymbol" : "-Infinito",
        "NegativeSign" : "-",
        "NumberDecimalDigits" : 2,
        "NumberDecimalSeparator" : ",",
        "NumberGroupSeparator" : ".",
        "NumberGroupSizes" : [3],
        "NumberNegativePattern" : 1,
        "PerMilleSymbol" : "‰",
        "PercentDecimalDigits" : 2,
        "PercentDecimalSeparator" : ",",
        "PercentGroupSeparator" : ".",
        "PercentGroupSizes" : [3],
        "PercentNegativePattern" : 1,
        "PercentPositivePattern" : 1,
        "PercentSymbol" : "%",
        "PositiveInfinitySymbol" : "+Infinito",
        "PositiveSign" : "+"
    }
} );
if ( typeof ( DeferWebFormInitCallback ) == 'function' ) DeferWebFormInitCallback();

function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    _saveMarkedElems();
    UpdateFormDigest( '\u002fsites\u002fdist', 1440000 );
    var workspaceElem = GetCachedElement( "s4-workspace" );
    if ( workspaceElem != null ) {
        var scrollElem = GetCachedElement( "_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition" );
        if ( scrollElem != null ) {
            scrollElem.value = workspaceElem.scrollTop;
        }
    };
    if ( typeof ( SP ) != 'undefined' &&
        SP.Ribbon &&
        SP.Ribbon.PageState &&
        SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateHandler &&
        SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateHandler
        .pageStateOnSubmit ) SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateHandler.pageStateOnSubmit();
    if ( typeof ( _spFormOnSubmitWrapper ) != 'undefined' ) {
        return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();
    } else {
        return true;
    };
    return true;
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize( 'ctl00$ScriptManager',
    'aspnetForm',
    ['fctl00$WebPartAdderUpdatePanel', ''],
    [],
    ['ctl00$WebPartAdder', ''],
    90,
    'ctl00' );

WebForm_InitCallback();
```

Comment: Just the errors is not very useful. It would be more useful, if you also provide the information WHERE (in which files and on which position) these errors occur (just make a screenshot where the additional information for these error is "popped up". 
Could be a string that is closed too soon, some part which is expecting a exact URL (but in this case you have to make sure that everything is site-relative), ...

Comment: You said "Web Parts, lists and libraries are not loaded" so it is not JS error but you have configuration problem in the FBA?

Comment: Check the syntax which you have bind to the html. Also give those couple of lines so that one can check that issue!!

Comment: @mark the FBA configuration is correct. I have JS errors on browser, but the user can navigate and open links.

Comment: I have added the function are getting error.

Comment: Your errors indicate basic JavaScript issues.  Your code doesn't show where `Sys` is created.  You cannot access a method or property of an object that is undefined.  `WebForm_InitCallback()` is also not defined anywhere.  If there's a SharePoint issue here, we cannot fix it until the basic JavaScript ones are fixed.  Until then, this is off topic, and should be in StackOverflow.

Comment: This functions are native of SharePoint and in another address I not receive this error. In this address I have a extended WEB APP of first and FBA, jut this.

Comment: I suspect the error in the function...Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ( function( a ) {
    return new Sys.CultureInfo( a.name, a.numberFormat, a.dateTimeFormat );
} )( {....   

change it to

Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ( function( a ) {
    return new Sys.CultureInfo( a.name, a.numberFormat, a.dateTimeFormat );
}, {....

Comment: You say that your site is published in two different sites. This could mean that the if you have the same    <script src="..." tags both places they will only be correct for one of the sites and not the other. You could try to go over them and see if the file locations for the scripts are correct in the site that throws the errors

Comment: It's exactly the same site, I have one web app and the same web app extended.

Comment: Then what do you mean by  "published in two addresses"?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the scripts and webparts that you are using have sufficient user permissions. Also make sure that the scripts loaded are published and are shared with everyone in FBA.

Comment: Yes, the group everyone and everyone FBA users have read and edit permissions

Comment: Please check your master page, might be a possibility that some one must have put a script in master page and because of that error are being displayed in the browser

Comment: I have checked, but aparently all is OK. I will check again, but I thinking is also in configuration of IIS.

Comment: I have added the function are getting error.

Comment: I down-voted 'cause this should've been a comment rather than an answer.